"Version Solving Failed: fluttertoast depends on fluttertoast - How to resolve this dependency conflict?"
I'm encountering a dependency issue while using the fluttertoast package in my Flutter project. When I try to run flutter pub get, I get the following error message:
Because fluttertoast depends on fluttertoast, version solving failed.
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
fluttertoast: ^8.2.8
I tried cleaning the project (flutter clean), upgrading dependencies (flutter pub upgrade), and even overriding the dependency in the dependency_overrides section, but the issue persists.
Could someone help me understand what might be causing this error, and how I can resolve it? Is there something wrong with how I'm specifying the fluttertoast dependency, or is there a conflict I am overlooking?
Running flutter clean and flutter pub get
Updating the version of fluttertoast and other dependencies
Using dependency_overrides in pubspec.yaml

This happens when there is name collision between your project and the dependency.
I would guess you have named your project fluttertoast.

Because fluttertoast depends on fluttertoast, version solving failed.

The first fluttertoast refers to your current project while the second fluttertoast refers to the actual package.
Rename the name field in your pubspec.yaml to something else should fix the issue.
